# Convergence in distribution, CLT, and the delta method

Tags: self-study

I have a self-study problem solution, and I am trying to figure how it was solved. The problem is below:

Let $X_{i}, i=1,2,...,$ be independent bernoulli(p) random varianbles and let $Y_{n}=$ ${1}\over{n}$ $\sum$ $X_{i}$. Show that for $p$ not equal to $1/2$, the estimate of variance $Y_{n}(1-Y_{n})$ satisfies $n^{1/2}[Y_{n}(1-Y_{n})-p(1-p)^2]$ $\longrightarrow$ $N[0,(1-2p)^2$ $p(1-p)]$ in distribution.

The solution is given as:

Write,
$n^{1/2}[Y_{n}(1-Y_{n})-p(1-p)]$ $=$ $n^{1/2}([Y_{n}-p)(1-Y_{n})+p(1-Y_{n})-p(1-p)]$ $=$ $n^{1/2}(Y_{n}-p)(1-Y_{n})+$ $n^{1/2}$$p(p-Y_{n})$ $=$ $n^{1/2}$$(Y_{n}-p)(1-2p)-n^{1/2}(Y_{n}-p)^2$ Now if p is not 1/2, repeatedly using Slutsky's Theorem, we get $n^{1/2}(Y_{n}-p)(1-2p)$ $\longrightarrow$ $N[0,(1-2p)^2$ $p(1-p)^2]$ in distribution.

I know that the delta method is supposed to be used in solving this problem, but I can not see how it was applied to the above solutions. For example using the delta method (this is a shortend version) we would get $N[0,\sigma^2$$(g'(p))^{2]}$$ $=$ $$N[0,(1-2p)^2$ $p(1-p)]$ in distribution.$N[0,(1-2p)^2$ $p(1-p)]$ in distribution.

Can anyone follow the first solution (from the manual) that I gave above? That's how I am supposed to solve it in the class....

Comment: You need to show that the second term converges to zero in probability. Then by Slutzky's theorem, you have your result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:

What is the limiting distribution of the random variable

$$n\left(Y_n-p \right)^2$$

Recall now that convergence in distribution implies boundedness in probability. Conclude that

$$\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-p \right)^2 \xrightarrow{P} 0$$

Comment: Limiting distribution is $n\left(Y_n-p \right)^2$ standard normal? And I suppose $Y_{n}$ converges to p, so $\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-p \right)^2 \xrightarrow{P} 0$ ... but ultimately still not seeing any connection.

Comment: It's not standard normal but in any case, it will help if you rewrite the term as $$\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-p \right)^2 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left[ n\left(Y_n-p \right)^2 \right] $$ Do you see where I am going with this now?

Comment: Well I see that if $Y_{n}$ converges to p, it takes care of that second term..... but where does that 2nd term come from in the first place??? I see that it's equal, but why rewrite the problem in that way? Further, after you establish that $Y_{n}$ converges to p, why is the derivate (1-2p) inserted into the problem? I am very confused on this topic, sorry....